# Cannot get a path reference in Firebase Storage with getDownloadURL() - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload some images and get them back with the .getDownloadURL() method however it won't work. I works fine in a different part of the app when I update the user profile picture but won't work in the following example:

```
 memory.files.forEach(async (file) => {
      const response = await fetch(file);
      const blob = await response.blob();

      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`files/${file.slice(-10)}`)
        .put(blob)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("file upladed");
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('BIG ERROE'));
        

      var pathReference = await firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`files/${file.slice(-10)}`)
        .getDownloadURL();
      pathRefs.push(pathReference);
    });
```

This is the error I get :

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 8):
p {
  "code_": "storage/object-not-found",
  "message_": "Firebase Storage: Object 'files/img.jpg' does not exist.",
  "name_": "FirebaseError",
  "serverResponse_": "{
  \"error\": {
    \"code\": 404,
    \"message\": \"Not Found.  Could not get object\",
    \"status\": \"GET_OBJECT\"
  }
}",
}
```

It's not related to the security rules since it works when uploading and getting back the profile picture. I'm really struggling why I get the error since I'm following the exact same pattern as whit the profile pic upload. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code isn't waiting for the upload to complete before getting the download URL.  Since you are using async/await, you can wait for the upload to finish using the promise returned by put(), then fetch the URL the same way you are doing now:

```
      await firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`files/${file.slice(-10)}`)
        .put(blob);

        console.log("file upladed");

      var pathReference = await firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`files/${file.slice(-10)}`)
        .getDownloadURL();

      pathRefs.push(pathReference);
```

If you need error handling, use try/catch around the whole thing.  Don't mix then/catch callbacks with async/await and try/catch as you are now

Comment: The files get uploaded successfully at the exact file path on in Storage. It's just weird